# Problema con Delay artifical en aplicacion Java Swing

Tags: java, java-swing, timer, paint, repaint

estoy realizando un juego en Java y me surgió un problema que no soy capaz de resolver. Este tiene un sistema de turnos bastante sencillo.

```
    public void jugar(Accion A) {
        this.realizar(A, this.JA, this.JB);
        this.restablecer();
        this.respuesta();
    }
```

donde:

- Accion: Objeto que contiene la decisión del jugador.
- Realizar: Hace que surta efecto la Acción del jugador y comprueba las condiciones de victoria.
- restablecer: Limpia la interfaz del jugador, y reinicia los botones y demás elementos.
- Respuesta: Pide al oponente que le de una acción y ejecuta un Realizar desde su perspectiva.

sin embargo en la practica todo esto sucede en solo 1ms y siento que se ve feo. de hecho hace poco comprensible lo que ocurre en la partida. Por lo que busque hacer esto:

```
    public void jugar(Accion A) {
        this.realizar(A, this.JA, this.JB);
        this.restablecer();
        this.delay(150);
        this.respuesta();
    }
```

Probé con un Swing.Timer, un Thread.Sleep y con ambos no conseguí que se viera primero la acción del jugador A y luego la del B. Ya que la Interfaz no se esta repintando, incluso cuando le mande a hacerlo.

De hecho se produce la pausa, pero la pantalla se actualiza mas tarde. Puede que el problema este en el hecho de que estén en un método aparte y no en main. Aun así se me hace raro. Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Desde dónde invocas a *jugar()*?

Comment: Dependiendo de la situación parten de dos puntos distintos.

A) Un método en la misma clase
B) Un evento ActionPerformed de un boton.

Igualmente el A parte del mismo punto que el B. Solamente que el B tiene que hacer ams recorrido para verificar unas cosas del juego.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Swing, el mismo hilo de ejecución (*thread*) que invoca a tus *listener* es el que redibuja la ventana. Así que hasta que no salgas de la ejecución del *listener*, no redibujará la ventana.

La solución es que, si la lógica del *listener* va a tardar algún tiempo, pasar la lógica a un *thread* distinto para que el *thread* de Swing salga de tu listener y se dedique a dibujar mientras tu programa hace sus cosas.

```
public void jugar(Accion A) {
    MiThread miThread = new MiThread(componente); // componente = el componente a redibujar después de cada jugada.
    miThread.start();
} 

public class MiThread extends Thread {
   private JComponent componente;

   public MiThread(JComponent componente) {
      this.componente = componente;
   }

   public void run() {
    this.realizar(A, this.JA, this.JB);
    this.componente.repaint();
    this.restablecer();
    this.delay(150);
    this.respuesta();
    this.componente.repaint();
  }
}
```

Aquí *jugar* solo creará el thread y lo pondrá en marcha, y devolverá el control a Swing para que redibuje la ventana. Mientras, por separado el otro *thread* se ejecutará e invocará a *repaint* para que *Swing* actualice el componente afectado cuando toque.