# Problema con el netbeans y los audio mp3

Tags: java, mp3, javazoom

Resulta que le quiero añadir música la cual ya le añadir este es el código

```
private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         try{
             
             FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\javie\\Desktop\\java\\TunningCoche\\src\\audio\\pas.mp3");
             Player playMP3 = new Player(fis);
             playMP3.play();
        }  catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Pero no me funciona ningún botón que tengo programado. Pero sin embargo si comento la parte de la música funciona los botones perfectamente alguna solución. Gracias de Antemano

```
private void botonSalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.exit(WIDTH);
    }
```

es el unico boton que tengo puesto y es un boton de salir

video de lo que me pasa [Enlace al video sobre lo que me hace el programa](https://youtu.be/b80Q3JHmhi0)

Comment: Es tan sólo una sugerencia, pero para que se pueda valorar correctamente, igual lo ideal sería que pusieras también el código del botón.

Comment: vale ahora lo pongo

Comment: listo ya lo puse

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema con Delay artifical en aplicacion Java Swing](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/358781/problema-con-delay-artifical-en-aplicacion-java-swing)

Comment: lo siento pero no

Comment: mirra el enlace esta el video de lo que me llega a ser

Comment: me he dado cuenta que error viene del playMP3.play(); cuando lo sustituyo por otra cosa funciona pero no se escucha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compañero, he hecho una prueba muy básica con un jframe y un botón salir, y de la forma que te muestro en el código me funciona perfectamente. Es decir, **al entrar en el programa la música se reproduce de fondo y al hacer click sobre el botón salir, sale del programa**.

Dos opciones:

**Usando .MP3**:

Este, por lo que veo, sería tu caso. He generado el método auxiliar **ReproducirSonidoMP3()** que recibe un String con el nombre del audio que quieras reproducir:

```
    public void ReproducirSonidoMP3(String nombreSonido) {
    String ruta = nombreSonido;
    Media hit = new Media(new File(ruta).toURI().toString());
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

Para que **no dé error "Toolkit not initialized"**, añade esta línea al código, fuera del método:

```
 final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
```

Para que **la música no se pare a los pocos segundos** (es culpa del Garbage Collector, si creamos el MediaPlayer fuera del método, se soluciona), añade esta línea:

```
private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
```

Lo implemento de esta forma sobre el **jFrame**:

```
    private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
    try {
        ReproducirSonidoMP3("song2.mp3");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

**Usando .WAV**:

He generado un método auxiliar **ReproducirSonidoWav()** que recibe también un String con el nombre del audio que quieras reproducir:

```
    public void ReproducirSonidoWav(String nombreSonido) {
    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(nombreSonido).getAbsoluteFile());
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error al reproducir el sonido.");
    }
}
```

Y lo implemento sobre el evento del **jFrame**:

```
private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
    try {
        ReproducirSonidoWav("song1.wav");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Estos serían los **imports** necesarios:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda :)

Comment: lo voy a mirrar

Comment: hay que poner algun import?

Comment: Por supuesto, edito y te los pongo al final de la solución.

Comment: vale y muchas gracias

Comment: Nada, para eso estamos... a ver si adaptándolo te sirve.

Comment: import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer; me da error como existe por cierto como te puedo dar 50 de reputacion

Comment: Supongo que puedes confirmar la respuesta :)

Respecto a los imports, esos son los imports que uso en mi archivo y no me da ningún problema. Revisa el resto del código a ver si tienes algo duplicado.

Comment: vale puede ser que haya que añadir la libreria

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112374/discussion-between-pablohs1986-and-javier-g-raya).